# Checkbox state based on function Angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-template, angular-changedetection

In my component, I have two arrays of items: `allItems` and `selectedItems` (using dummy names here, of course). The selection is handled by checkbox controls and their state depends on whether an item is found in `selectedItems`.

Since I need to evaluate checkbox state based on an expression, I need to call a function, like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of allItems; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox"
                [checked]="itemChecked(item .Id)"
                (change)="toggleItem(i)">
    <label class="form-check-label" [for]="item.Id">{{ item.Value }}</label>
</div>
```

And the function goes something like:

```
itemChecked(id: number) {
    return this.selectedItems.findIndex(x => x.Id == id) > -1;
}
```

The problem is the `itemChecked` executes nonstop. I've read before this can maybe be solved using directives, but if that is even the case, I can't find any concrete example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom pipe in order to check for changes.

The custom pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'isItemChecked'
})
export class IsItemCheckedPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(selectedItems: any[], id: number) {
    return selectedItems.findIndex(x => x.Id === id) > -1;
    // Or
    // return selectedItems.some(x => x.Id === id);
  }

}
```

And in the template:

```
<input type="checkbox"
                [checked]="selectedItems | isItemChecked:item.Id"
                (change)="toggleItem(i)">
```